# Send email reminder every 1st friday

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to create a workflow wherein the SP will send an email reminder every 1st first friday of the month to a certain group. I already created a list. Thanks!

Comment: Is it SharePoint Online /Office 365 or on premise sharepoint  that you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

To make your workflow as a reminder service would not be an ideal choice. I would suggest something like a scheduled task that can calculate if its the first Friday of the month logic and then if yes to create an item in a list (from Powershell ) which can then trigger the workflow to send emails on new items created. If you are ok with this type of approach then we can look into it further.

Answer (score 1):

It would easier to use [Microsoft Flow](https://india.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/) for the purpose.

Check out this [link](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/Trigger-on-first-Monday-of-the-Month/td-p/39220), a similar task has been done

Hope this helps